# Meaning of wait((int *)0)

Tags: c, pipe, fork

One such program that uses a wait function like this is this one:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int pid,fd[2]; int n; char line[20];        
    if(pipe(fd)<0) { 
        printf("Error creating pipe"); 
    } else { 
        pid=fork(); 
        if(pid<0) { 
            printf("Error while forking"); 
        } else { 
            if(pid>0) { 
                close(fd[0]); 
                write(fd[1],"Hello\n",6); 
                while(wait((int *)0)!=pid);
            } else { 
                close(fd[1]); 
                n=read(fd[0],line,20); 
                if(n<0) 
                printf("Error reading a file"); 
                write(1,line,n); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If only the sample code had anything to do with threads.

Comment: @Sean -- did you miss the fork() call?

Comment: Nope.  I see it.  Still has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: @Sean -- I see. The edits to the question removed the threads references in the text.  I thought you were inferring that there was nothing to wait on.  Of course, it's a process not a thread that is being waited on.

Comment: @tvanfosson: yes, I originally commented when "thread" was still in the title/body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stager's answer is correct. Though it should be noted that the cast is entirely unnecessary since according to the standard, 0 used in a pointer context is the NULL pointer.

Answer (score 15):

See [man wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

`wait((int *)0)` calls `waitpid(-1, (int *)0, 0)`.  The man page states:

> If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points.

Here, `status` is NULL (0).  Thus, your call to `wait` waits for a state change in any child process, and does not return a status.  The call merely checks to see if a state change occurred for a specific child process (`pid` in your case).

Answer (score 1):

The argument `status_ptr` points to a location where `wait()` can store a status value. This status value is zero if the child process explicitly returns zero status. If it is not zero, it can be analyzed with the status analysis macros, described in “Status Analysis Macros,” below.

> **The `status_ptr` pointer may also be `NULL`**, in which case `wait()` ignores the child's return status.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=functions-wait-wait-child-process-end