# What does (int* ) 0 mean when calling wait() function?

Tags: c, linux, pointers

`wait()` is a system call in Linux system:

```
int wait(int *status)
```

> Wait for a child to exit; exit status in *status; returns child PID.

```
int pid = fork();
if(pid > 0){
    printf("parent: child=%d\n", pid);
    pid = wait((int *) 0);
    printf("child %d is done\n", pid);
} else if(pid == 0){
    printf("child: exiting\n");
    exit(0);
} else {
    printf("fork error\n");
}
```

I feel confused about `pid = wait((int *) 0);`,the sign of `int wait(int *status)` says it needs a pointer of int,but when calling it by`pid = wait((int *) 0)`,is it converting `0` to a pointer,and pid becomes the exact pid of the child? If I am wrong,could anyone pleadse explain what is happening to me?

Comment: `(int *)0` is a "null pointer".  This response (which *ISN'T* the "accepted" answer - but it should be) explains it's significance in [wait()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html): https://stackoverflow.com/a/690023/421195

Comment: In modern code, writing it as `wait(NULL)` would be more idiomatic.